# Why was this question on searching for [Equation] in a Word 365 online document closed as troubleshooting?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

The question [How can I search for equations that are displayed as [Equation] instead of the actual equation in a document in Word 365 online?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172059/18147) was closed as troubleshooting:

> I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications. [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n)**♦**  ([link to comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/172059/how-can-i-search-for-equations-that-are-displayed-as-equation-instead-of-the-a?noredirect=1#comment161287_172059); [all comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnA92.png))

In my opinion, the question is not about troubleshooting, it’s simply a question on how to search some elements in a Word 365 online document. Why was it closed as troubleshooting?

Comment: Consider editing the question to clarify that you are not interested in explanations about why a gray background and the text `[Equation]` are showing instead of the actual equation, either on why the find text feature of Word Online is not able to find the questions when you search `[Equation]` and how to make it work. Be clear that you are open to an answer that says, "It's not possible" without explaining why and that you are not interested in a workaround and on nothing that requires details not already included in the question and might require you to invest additional time.

Comment: You should include that you are not looking for any kind of guidance that requires back-and-forth interactions other than the basic spelling grammar and tag improvements alike and that you just want a direct and definite answer based on the information provided in the question body.

Comment: The above is just an idea of how could be clarified that the question is not a troubleshooting question.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks, I added it in the question (except for "I am not interested in a workaround": I didn't add that, I don't believe a question must exclude workarounds to avoid getting closed). Can the question be reopened?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been a MS Office power user since its first release. Because this question mentions several complex elements that might vary based on each user's circumstances, it looked like a troubleshooting-like question.

Please ensure that questions don't invite back-and-forth interaction beyond the normal post-clarification / improvement.

---

After the question was edited, it was reopened.

Remember that if the question gets answers and you or a commenter have follow-up questions, those questions should be posted as new questions on a site where each question is on topic. I.E. In Web Applications SE, questions about Word Online are on-topic, but the following are off-topic:

- General questions about the equations editors over the different versions of MS Word.
- Asking for recommendations for Word Online plug-ins / add-ons.
- Office JavaScript API scripts.

If you need help finding a site to ask questions about something off-topic in Web Applications SE, request a site recommendation on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

There is always the option to invite people having +20 rep to participate in the question to have a conversation in a chatroom. A mod might invite new users.